# Как при нажатии кнопки остановить вывод текста в Qlabel, а при повторном нажатии действие продолжалось?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Как при нажатии кнопки остановить вывод текста в `Qlabel`, а при повторном нажатии действие продолжалось?

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QApplication, QMessageBox, QPushButton, QLabel, QInputDialog
from PyQt5 import QtGui


class Game(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.play = True
        self.btn_pause = QPushButton('||', self)
        self.btn_pause.setGeometry(377, 3, 20, 20)
        self.btn_pause.clicked.connect(self.pause)
        self.text = f'После того, как запустите этот код, обратите внимание на то,\nчто ярлык возникает некорректно, так как\
 размер — меньше,\nчем размер шрифта, который мы используем. Так что нам\nнужно установить размер ярлыка.'
        self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        self.lbl.setGeometry(20, 349, 460, 78)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.print_text)
        self.timer.start(30)

        self.new = [i for i in self.text]
        self.len_new = len(self.new)
        self.num = 0

        self.resize(400, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Квест')

    def pause(self):
        if self.btn_pause.text() == '||':
            self.btn_pause.setText('>')
            self.play = False
        else:
            self.btn_pause.setText('||')
            self.play = True

    def print_text(self):
        if self.play:
            self.lbl.setText(self.lbl.text() + self.new[self.num])
            self.lbl.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
            self.num += 1
            if self.num == self.len_new:
                self.timer.stop()
            return
        else:
            while not self.play:
                continue
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Game()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте нажимать кнопку и после того как весь текст отобразится.

```
import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QEventLoop, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QDesktopWidget, QApplication, QMessageBox, \
    QPushButton, QLabel, QInputDialog
from PyQt5 import QtGui


class Game(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.play = True
        self.btn_pause = QPushButton('||', self)
        self.btn_pause.setGeometry(377, 3, 20, 20)
        self.btn_pause.clicked.connect(self.pause)
        self.text = f'После того, как запустите этот код, обратите внимание на то, \n'\
                    f'что ярлык возникает некорректно, так как '\
                    f'размер — меньше,\nчем размер шрифта, который мы используем. '\
                    f'Так что нам\nнужно установить размер ярлыка.'
        self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        self.lbl.setGeometry(20, 349, 460, 78)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.print_text)
        self.timer.start(30)

        self.new = [i for i in self.text]
        self.len_new = len(self.new)
        self.num = 0

        self.resize(400, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Квест')

    def pause(self):
        if self.btn_pause.text() == '||':
            self.btn_pause.setText('>')
#            self.play = False
            self.timer.stop()                                        # +++
        else:
            self.btn_pause.setText('||')
#            self.play = True
            self.timer.start(30)                                     # +++

    def print_text(self):
#        if self.play:

        if len(self.lbl.text()) == self.len_new:                     # +++
            self.lbl.clear()                                         # +++
        
        self.lbl.setText(self.lbl.text() + self.new[self.num])
        self.lbl.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        self.num += 1
        if self.num == self.len_new:
            self.timer.stop()
#            self.lbl.setText(self.lbl.text() + '\n')
            self.num = 0                                             # +++
            self.btn_pause.setText('>')                              # +++
#            return
#        else:
#            while not self.play:
#                continue
                
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Game()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @kostya_09 Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour